# Deployed war file on tomcat gives 404 error

Tags: tomcat, ant, http-status-code-404

I have successfully deployed my war file of a small web application using an ant `build.xml` file to my local tomcat 7.0.42 server. When I type in the url to my application, `localhost:8080/springapp/index.jsp`, I get a 404 error.  I don't understand why I get an error when the war file is deployed.

I know my deployment is successful because I can see the `/springapp` listed in the tomcat manager app, `localhost:8080/manager`.  I have been following this tutorial, http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html, almost exactly besides altering a few things because I am using tomcat 7 and it is using tomcat 6. I am currently on step 1.4.
Any help would be much appreciated, I've been stuck on this problem for over a day of googling and troubleshooting.

Here is my build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="springapp" basedir="." default="usage">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="name" value="springapp"/>

    <path id="master-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <!-- We need the servlet API classes: -->
        <!--  * for Tomcat 5/6 use servlet-api.jar -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="servlet*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="usage">
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="${name} build file"/>
        <echo message="-----------------------------------"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="Available targets are:"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="build     --> Build the application"/>
        <echo message="deploy    --> Deploy application as directory"/>
        <echo message="deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file"/>
        <echo message="install   --> Install application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="reload    --> Reload application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="start     --> Start Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="stop      --> Stop Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="list      --> List Tomcat applications"/>
        <echo message=""/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true"
               deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy application">
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
        <war destfile="${name}.war"
             webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </war>
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="*.war"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

     <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/lib">
            <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
            <include name="tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
            <include name="tomcat-util.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${appserver.home}/bin">
            <include name="tomcat-juli.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>
    <taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
        <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
        <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}"
                 war="${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
        <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
        <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
        <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                 path="/${name}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
        <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                 username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                 password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome>
                index.jsp
            </welcome>
        </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here is my properties.build file:

```
appserver.home=/Users/joe/projects/tomcat
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib

deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps

tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager/text
tomcat.manager.username=someone
tomcat.manager.password=something
```

Here is my tomcat-users.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <user username="someone" password="something" 
          roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: The app is deployed, but is it started? What do the tomcat logs say?

Comment: What do you mean by is the app started?  I started tomcat via terminal with sh startup.sh.  Then I deploy it using the ant build.  About checking the logs, which one should I check and what should I be looking for?  There are localhost, localhost-access, catalina, catalina.out, and manager logs.  I checked them all and there were no error messages, if that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Look at the usage indications in the ant file. What target do you execute? Do you ever execute the `start` target which, as the usage indicates, is used to start the application?

Comment: Ok no I hadn't started the application. So now I tried starting tomcat, deploying the application, and then starting the application with the 'ant start' command in terminal.  All actions indicate successful deploys and starts, but I still get a 404 error.

Comment: I solved the problem.  My index.jsp file was located in /webapps/springapp/WEB-INF/index.jsp when it should have been in /webapps/springapp/index.jsp.  Stupid mistake. Thank you for your help JB Nizet.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. My index.jsp file was located /webapps/springapp/WEB-INF/index.jsp when it should have been /webapps/springapp/index.jsp. Stupid mistake. Thank you for your help JB Nizet.

Comment: hahaha, I made the exact mistake and you solved my problem, I don't even know why it happend, 'cause I also knew where it was correct to put it!